# Using Arduino GSM with WiFi

Tags: esp8266, wifi, gsm, arduino-yun

I have a project that requires  data to be sent online from a moving bus. I am using ESP8266F modules to send the data.

I am wondering what Arduino modules to buy that will act as an access point with wifi and will connect to the internet through GSM.

In this configuration, the ESP8266 will connect to the access point and will upload the data online.

I want to connect a DF robot "SIM808 GPS/GPRS/GSM Shield For Arduino" to an Arduino Yun and use them as a wifi access point to connect to the internet through GSM connection.

The ESP8266 (5 of them) will connect to the Arduino Yun and will then send variables to the internet through the internet connection provided by the GSM.

Comment: Please explain better. How many nodes are sending data? You need a GSM module that can act as an access point as well?

Comment: Why not just use a cheap Android phone?

Comment: GSM modules tend to use large amounts of current when transmitting so you *might* find that the ESP modules reset.  Why by an Arduino, stick to an ESP8226 and use that as you access point.

Comment: All the ESP (5) are connected individually with their own power supply and they all record certain analog value to be sent to GOOGLE spreadsheet using pushingbox. And my instructor already rejected the idea of using a cheap Android phone.

Answer (score 1):

ESP is a full stack WiFi module. If you are intended to collect some data from several ESPs you can configure one more as an access point and collect those data from other ESPs as stations. At access pint you can make a small web server as well. To send aggregated data through GSM then you can use a GSM module wire-connected to this ESP. To avoid RF interference while GSM sends data, you should use different power sources and shielded twisted pair for connection. It may happan, that you will need to place GSM module at some distance from ESP access point to avoid overload of the receiver. Even better to use external antennae outside the bus for GSM and shield it inside the bus to minimise the interference. I do not see how Arduino can help here.

Comment: Maxim, that a good idea but I have to upload the data (analog data) from the different ESPs to GOOGLE spreadsheet using pushingbox. Is it possible to send the data through the web server of the access point ESP connected to the GSM. And is it possible to connect ESP to GSM?